# How to map json to class models?

Tags: c#, json, class

I've been trying to work with jsons but my way was really stupid and had to code a lot more line without a model. So I want to learn how to map to models and how to use them.

This is the model:

```
namespace Chino.Models
{
    public class Event
    {
        public string display_html { get; set; }
        public string beatmap_id { get; set; }
        public string beatmapset_id { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string epicfactor { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profile
    {
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string join_date { get; set; }
        public string count300 { get; set; }
        public string count100 { get; set; }
        public string count50 { get; set; }
        public string playcount { get; set; }
        public string ranked_score { get; set; }
        public string total_score { get; set; }
        public string pp_rank { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string pp_raw { get; set; }
        public string accuracy { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_ss { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_ssh { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_s { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_sh { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_a { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string total_seconds_played { get; set; }
        public string pp_country_rank { get; set; }
        public List<Event> events { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is the code:

```
string url = $"http://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k={k}&u={username}";
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    Profile profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Profile>(json);


                    embed.WithThumbnailUrl($"https://a.ppy.sh/{profile.user_id}");
                    embed.WithAuthor($"{username} #{profile.pp_rank}, {profile.pp_raw}PP", Context.Guild.CurrentUser.GetAvatarUrl(), $"https://osu.ppy.sh/users/{user_id}");
                    embed.WithDescription($"Join date:{profile.join_date}\nCountry:{profile.country} #{profile.pp_country_rank}\nAccuray:{double.Parse(profile.accuracy):F2}%\nPlaycount:{profile.playcount}");                 
                    embed.WithColor(154, 255, 0);
                    await ReplyAsync($"", false, embed.Build());
                    client.Dispose();
                }
```

I made the model with json2csharp and so I don't think the problem is in the model.

```
[{"user_id":"7794035","username":"Citrom","join_date":"2016-01-20 17:21:57","count300":"5285260","count100":"992638","count50":"84329","playcount":"35721","ranked_score":"7215598829","total_score":"33075404306","pp_rank":"67927","level":"100.061","pp_raw":"3602.27","accuracy":"94.95156860351562","count_rank_ss":"21","count_rank_ssh":"6","count_rank_s":"292","count_rank_sh":"408","count_rank_a":"569","country":"HU","total_seconds_played":"2090643","pp_country_rank":"295","events":[{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #666 on <a href='\/b\/1706256?m=0'>Sangatsu no Phantasia - Collage (TV Size) [CRN's Insane]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1706256","beatmapset_id":"805425","date":"2019-08-28 20:14:27","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #282 on <a href='\/b\/2025119?m=0'>Kajiura Yuki - Administrator [Insane]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2025119","beatmapset_id":"967707","date":"2019-08-28 19:47:15","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/C_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #799 on <a href='\/b\/2025119?m=0'>Kajiura Yuki - Administrator [Insane]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2025119","beatmapset_id":"967707","date":"2019-08-28 19:44:43","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #100 on <a href='\/b\/1399403?m=0'>Poppin'Party - Natsu no Don! [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1399403","beatmapset_id":"653523","date":"2019-08-28 19:20:41","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #23<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2085890?m=0'>Day6 - Man in a movie [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2085890","beatmapset_id":"745457","date":"2019-08-28 15:43:27","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/D_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #327 on <a href='\/b\/1774124?m=0'>Haywyre - Insight [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1774124","beatmapset_id":"848400","date":"2019-08-28 13:09:00","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/D_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #363 on <a href='\/b\/1774124?m=0'>Haywyre - Insight [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1774124","beatmapset_id":"848400","date":"2019-08-28 13:02:59","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #604 on <a href='\/b\/163117?m=0'>Shihori - Magic Girl !! [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"163117","beatmapset_id":"53519","date":"2019-08-28 11:30:24","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/7794035'>Citrom<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #236 on <a href='\/b\/1102401?m=0'>TRUE - Soundscape [Kencho's Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1102401","beatmapset_id":"508222","date":"2019-08-28 11:17:52","epicfactor":"1"}]}]
```

And when I use this I get this error message:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e . g. [1.2.3]) into type ' Chino . Models . Profile' because the type requires a JSON object (e . g. {"name":"value"}) to desrialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e. g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e . g. I Collection. I List) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1. position 1.
>
> Object reference not set to an instanceof an object.

Comment: Please. Read the error. You are trying to deserialize an array, not a single model.
Your JSON is [{ ....... }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because your JSON is an array, as error is telling you.
You may use something like

```
IEnumerable<Profile> profiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Profile>>(json);
```

And get first, iterate... but the problem is on your JSON.